# How to read CSV and track where certain value changes

Tags: perl, csv

I have a CSV file:

```
Name,Week,Planned,Passed
AST,01,5,8
KST,01,9,14
RST,01,76,23
AST,02,12,45
KST,02,5,4
RST,02,13,65
GST,02,76,12
LST,03,12,43
AST,04,54,34
```

I am reading from this file and populating an HTML file with Perl, based on the information in the CSV:

```
while (!eof(FH)) { //while csv file is opened


my $line = <FH>;

chomp $line;

my($name,$week,$planned,$passed) = split(",", $line);

$currentHash{$name}{"week"} = $week;
$currentHash{$name}{"week"} = $planned;
$currentHash{$name}{"week"} = $passed;

$datafile = area/${week}/test.html

open my $fh, ">", $datafile;

if ($week != "Week") {

push @weekArray, qq( <td aligh=center bgcolor=#FFFFF font size='2'>$name</td>\n);

push @weekArray, qq( <td aligh=center bgcolor=#FFFFF font size='2'>$week</td>\n);

push @weekArray, qq( <td aligh=center bgcolor=#FFFFF font size='2'>$planned</td>\n);

push @weekArray, qq( <td aligh=center bgcolor=#FFFFF font size='2'>$passed</td>\n);


} //end of if

print $fh @weekArray;
close $fh

} //end of while
```

This code successfuly creates the table with the CSV file information. However, it does not create a table that creates a newline character after a new `week`.

I am having a hard time figuring out how to detect when a new week starts because it is all inside of a loop.

When I read the file, I want to place a newline character every time the week number changes. I also need to do this without hardcoding for a specific week, because the week number is arbitrary.

How I want the table to look like:

```
Name,Week,Planned,Passed
AST,01,5,8
KST,01,9,14
RST,01,76,23

AST,02,12,45
KST,02,5,4
RST,02,13,65
GST,02,76,12

LST,03,12,43

AST,04,54,34
```

Comment: Introduce an extra variable. Check if the currently read week is different form the one in that variable. If it is push empty cells in the array and set the variable to the currently read week.

Comment: Please, post actual runnable Perl code. Comments start with `#` in Perl, not `//`. Quotes are missing around `area/${week}/test.html`. Regarding some mistakes you made: `$week != "Week"` should use `ne` instead of `!=` (this test works for now, but not for the reason you think it does). Finally, you are writing Perl, not C, so you should do `while (my $line = <FH>)` rather than your `!eof(FH)` stuff (and use a lexical file handle `$FH` rather than a global `FH`).

Comment: @FranceMadrid A suggestion, which is important: add `use warnings;` and `use strict` at the beginning, and follow messages to fix things until you get your code to work with them. Then never leave them out (I _always_ have them).

Comment: @FranceMadrid: "_This code successfuly ..._"  --- how? It doesn't even run, on multiple accounts.

Answer (score 2):

Just remember the last week encountered in a variable with a wider scope. Use [Text::CSV_XS](http://p3rl.org/Text::CSV_XS) to process CSV files.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Text::CSV_XS;

my $week = 'Week';
my $csv = 'Text::CSV_XS'->new({binary => 1, auto_diag => 1});
open my $fh, "<", shift or die $!;
while (my $row = $csv->getline($fh)) {
    print "\n" if $week ne $row->[1];
    $week = $row->[1];
    $csv->say(*STDOUT, $row);
}
```